# A Bonus homework question in Elementary Statics. A painter on a ladder put on a ledge

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics

we have been asked about a bonus question in Basic Statics as mentioned below. I would be glad if someone help me with it.

The question is: There is a painter which is going to work on a ladder as shown in the pictures below. The ladder is on a ledge, improper ledges can be dangerous which can either break or malfunction the ladder.
The given information is:

L=20ft, alpha:70 degrees, h=12ft, W (Weight of the painter): 200 pound, painter is 3 feet higher than ladder top.

1. Determine the point which the ladder will break caused by shear force.
2. Determine the point which the ladder will break caused by Bending moment, consider the base of the ladder as a free-to-turn pin connection.
3. Draw shear and bending diagram.

[image: Information of the picture is given as mentioned]

Comment: I myself think the shear will happen on the ledge and the bending will happen in the point of two parts of the ladder connecting together. But I have problem on drawing the vectors and diagrams for the shear and bending.

Comment: Given that this is a homework problem, can you edit into the question the specific concepts which are giving you difficulty? You've included the 3 questions your homework is asking, but your comment seems to suggest you're only unsure on how to handle the force diagram. Also, can you provide a picture of what you *think* the force diagram should look like?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a question regarding the "Basic Statics", let's make it simple:

a) The worker will cause an axial compressive force on the ladder $F_h = Wcos\theta$. The support at the eave (ledge) should be considered as roller support that can not prevent the ladder from sliding, so the axial force must be resisted and transferred from the upper segment of the ladder to the lower segment through a linkage within the overlapping region. The linkage is the weakest point that shear failure likely to occur. As depict in the figure below, $V = F_h  = Wcos\theta$.

[image]

b) Along the ladder, the maximum moment will occur at the support point at the eave(ledge), caused by the force $F_N$ ($F_N = Wsin\theta$) through the cantilever action, $M = F_N*a = Wsin\theta*a$.

Note, there is another potential breaking point caused by the effect of the moment. If we consider the fact that the ladder consists of two segments connected by the overlapping, then a force couple ($F_c$) must exist to resist the tendency of rotation as depicted in the figure below. However, I think it is beyond the scope of basic statics.

[image]

Further note, the force $F_c$ also contributes to the cause of shear failure. That is, the failure shear force $F_v = \sqrt{V^2 + F_c^2}$.

Based on the above notes, I don't think this is a well-thought question for the elementary engineering mechanics class/student. However, I could have misunderstood the questions or the depth of study in the class. Please do not hesitate to point out my mistakes.